# MQTT in Nativescript-Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, mqtt, nativescript-vue

Im making a nativescript-vue project and I will utilize MQTT however I cant see any library related to it. However there are libraries for MQTT Nativescript for TS, JS, Angular.. Can I apply this to tns vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved when edusperoni officially continued the work of krislankford for nativescript-mqtt. This is the new repo of nativescript-mqtt: https://github.com/edusperoni/nativescript-mqtt and works in any nativescript templates.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript / Angular / Vue, end of the day everything is just JavaScript. Especially when there is a feature available for NativeScript Core it should be easily accessible on the frameworks too, Angular / Vue.

Simply import the plugin in Vue and start using it, except removing the type declarations if you are using JavaScript for Vue development.

Comment: I will be using this package https://github.com/krislankford/nativescript-mqtt  .. I'll let you know. Thank you :)